# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC Appended after Querystring

Tags: asp.net, redirect, query-string, payment-gateway

I am creating a payment gateway test project

and and all works fine for testing and after final step when the success of the transaction is to be displayed to customer : the page has url like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/gateway/finalStatus.aspx?Result=Success&Amount=12345<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
```

Notice **`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC`** at the end

i use following syntax to redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("REDIRECT=http://www.mywebsite.com/gateway/finalStatus.aspx?Result="+Result+"&Amount="+Amount)
```

This is what the gateway people has suggested its mandatory to use **"REDIRECT"** before http

What could be reason and what is solution for this?

**EDIT :**

Sorry the syntax is like this:

```
Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://www.mywebsite.com/gateway/finalStatus.aspx?Result="+Result+"&Amount="+Amount)
```

and not `Response.Redirect`

Sorry for the mistake.
Now the problem is same. Any Help?

Comment: `REDIRECT=` seems to be at least one of the reasons it fails.

Comment: @Uwe i have made an edit in the question.
But the documents provided says it is mandatory to use `"REDIRECT="` word

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOt the solution:

on the page where i was was writing `Response.Write` ,
 Remove the Following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or similar lines.

For ex: if `Response.Write was` on `abc.aspx` then remove the above mentioned line from `abc.aspx`
This solves the problem.